# Solving a homogeneous DE as exact DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving a differential equation but instead of solving it as a homogeneous DE. I decided to use the exact DE.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+2xy-y^2}{x^2-2xy-y^2}$$

$$y(1)=-1$$

Can someone guide me how to?

Comment: Start from what the condition for 'exactness' is.

Comment: @G-man **My(x,y)= - Nx(x,y).** Is it still valid

Comment: @StacyBarrymore you need to find an integrating factor in order to make it exact, I can’t remember quite what it but I think it’s something like $\mathrm{exp}\left(\int\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}dx\text{ or }dy\right)$ like I said can’t remember

Comment: @Dylan I followed the usual method and end up with x-y=2,Can someone please confirm?

Comment: I'm not sure. It would help if you showed all the steps in the post

Answer (score 1):

HINT : An integrating factor is $\quad\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$

The method used to find it is shown in attachment :

[image]

So, the exact differential is :
$$\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\left((x^2+2xy-y^2)dx-(x^2-2xy+y^2)dy\right)=du=0$$

$u=\left(\int \frac{x^2+2xy-y^2}{(x+y)^2}dx\right)_{\text{at y=constant}}=\frac{2y^2}{x+y}+x+f(y)$

$u=\left(\int \frac{-(x^2-2xy-y^2)}{(x+y)^2}dy\right)_{\text{at x=constant}}=\frac{2x^2}{x+y}+y+g(x)$

$\frac{2y^2}{x+y}+x+f(y)-\frac{2x^2}{x+y}-y-g(x)=0 \quad\to\quad x+y+f(y)+g(x)=0$

$f(y)=-y\quad$ and $\quad g(x)=-x\quad$ which leads to :
$$u=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}=c \quad\to\quad x^2+y^2-c(x+y)=0$$
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(c\pm\sqrt{c^2+4cx-4x^2} \right)$$